# How to set threads number for Stockfish?

Tags: stockfish

How to set number of thread parameter for Stockfish?

I read about Stockfish parameters but there is not description how to set it?

http://support.stockfishchess.org/kb/advanced-topics/engine-parameters

Comment: yes there is no description on how to set tablebases in uci engine without using any chess gui!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read http://support.stockfishchess.org/kb/advanced-topics/uci-protocol

```
setoption name Threads value 4
```

Comment: Do you know if we need to change MinSplitDepth with 8 threads?

Comment: Link is dead now

Comment: @M.M The whole website is down.